# Magento Database Connecting other websites

Tags: mysql, magento

I want to connect Magento Database with my other website for login purposes. So that users do not need to register again.

For other websites I don't have Magento layer. Just raw PHP mysql websites.

I'm wondering what would be best way create a central database and how can I retrieve user information(username and password only.) from Magento Database.

I am thinking to execute raw php mysql queries but for that I need to open ports on my servers to connect to other servers because all websites are on different servers.

What would be the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve SSO (Single sign on) the best thing to do would be to migrate all your users to Magento.

The Magento files should be accessible on the external website too (either if they are on the same server or via a mount.) You can then use something like the code below:

```
<?php

require_once '/path/to/magento/root/app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app();

$session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');

// Login
try {
    $session->login($email, $password);
    $session->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($session->getCustomer());

    //Load the customer modules
    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId());

    //Get customer attribbutes
    $customer->loadByEmail($email);

} catch (Exception $e) {
    Mage::log($e->getMessage());
}
```

Where $email and $password would contain the values that are sent from a form

Comment: Is it like I can use php mount function to use external file location?

Comment: is possible if you could show me how to mount I am really not that good at linux or some hint.

Comment: I would do it using NFS See [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/10/nfs-mount-guide/) for more info

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got it. Just wondering isn't that somewhat similar to symbolic links?